# rails routes in path.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I have following route in my path.rb file in rails app. '/table_name/:id/edit' which points to edit.html file. I need to extract :id from incoming string "name" which is one of the rows of table. how can I do it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (at a higher level)?  Please explain with more detail or this is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use params to exract id

```
params[:id]
```